# exclude empty and hidden files when archiving

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I need to create an archive of a directory using `tar` **in a shell script** but I am also supposed to exclude hidden files and files whose size is equal to `0`. Also the first command line argument is the location of the archive which is supposed to be created, the second is the name of the archive and the third is the path to the directory whose files are supposed to be archived.

I tried sending the arguments like this in my terminal:

```
/bin/bash ss1 /home/user arch /home/user/folder
```

But it is giving me some tar errors.
I tried to archive like this:

```
tar -cvf --exclude=.* $1/$2 $3
```

But it is not correct and I am not sure what the right syntax for this would be, and also how I would exclude empty and hidden files.

Comment: the command just made an archive called --exclude=.*

Comment: You're not able to exclude empty files with tar you will need to make a shell script for that. To exclude a pattern the exclude needs to be placed before the source and destination.

Comment: @JazzCat I am doing all this in a shell script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you tagged this `linux` I'll assume you have GNU `find` and GNU `tar`.

If your filenames don't have embedded newlines and you don't want to archive empty directories:

```
find "$3" -type f \! -empty \! -name '.*' | tar cvf "$1/$2" -T -
```

`find` finds the relevant files, and `-T -` tells `tar` to read the list of files to archive from `stdin`.

Refining this, if you want to include empty directories:

```
find "$3" \( -type d -empty \) -o \( -type f \! -empty \! -name '.*' \) | \
    tar cvf "$1/$2" -T -
```

And if you *also* want to handle filenames with embedded newlines:

```
find "$3" \( \( -type d -empty \) -o \( -type f \! -empty \! -name '.*' \) \) -print0 | \
    tar cvf "$1/$2" --null -T -
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find test/ -not -iname ".*" -not -empty -exec tar --no-recursion -rvf file.tar {} \;
```

The only trouble is that empty directories will not be included, but i think there is some workaround somewhere...